# Mystery: Why do my new landscape lights (which aren't on wifi) show up on my Apple TV?

Tags: ios, appletv, airplay

I'm stumped...when I share a video from any iOS device I on (iPad, iPhone, etc) using AirPlay to my Apple TV three things happen:

- The audio is shared, but not the video
- I get a notification on the Apple TV with the name of my landscape lights (see screenshot)
- When I check the Airplay menu from other iOS devices, the menu has the name of my landscaping lights it in (see screenshot).

My landscaping lights are not connected to Wifi.  I've confirmed they're also not in Homekit.  I've tried unplugging the lights and no dice.  I've also tried sharing different videos from different iOS devices with different apps - always the same behavior.

Sharing from my Mac works as expected (both audio and video, none of this landscape lights nonsense).[image]

[image]

Comment: If they have wifi capability then why shouldn’t they show up?

Comment: They do not have a wifi antenna and are not connected to my network.

Comment: A visible wifi antenna isn't required. Many wifi devices have internal antennae, or use otherwise-innocuous external wiring for the antenna function.